# SQL Server CLR Assembly Repeatable Implementation Ordering?

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, implementation

I have a pair of CLR assemblies and I'm trying to create a repeatable implementation script.
Both assemblies need the EXTERNAL permission set, so I've got asymmetric keys involved as well, and these are causing problems.  As when you run it the second time you get the 'Cannot drop key, login mapped to it' error.

Some other q's I have with this are:
Do I need the login/key in the database and at server level?

At the moment my script is:

```
USE master
GO 

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'BaselCLRLogin')
    DROP LOGIN [BaselCLRLogin]
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.asymmetric_keys WHERE name = 'BaselCLRKey')
    DROP ASYMMETRIC KEY [BaselCLRKey]
GO

USE [BaselST]
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('clr.CheckFileFormat'))
    DROP PROCEDURE clr.CheckFileFormat
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'BaselCLRLogin')
    DROP USER [BaselCLRLogin]
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.assemblies asms WHERE asms.name = N'BaselCLR' and is_user_defined = 1)
    DROP ASSEMBLY [BaselCLR]
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.asymmetric_keys WHERE name = 'BaselCLRKey')
    DROP ASYMMETRIC KEY [BaselCLRKey]
GO

USE master
GO 

-- First Create the Asymmetric Key from the Assembly
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY BaselCLRKey
FROM EXECUTABLE FILE = 'D:\BASEL\BS_Assemblies\BaselCLR.dll'
GO

-- Create the Login from the Asymmetric Key
CREATE LOGIN BaselCLRLogin FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY BaselCLRKey
GO

-- Grant the External Access Priviledge to the Login
GRANT EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY TO BaselCLRLogin
GO

USE [BaselST] 
GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'clr')
    EXEC ('CREATE SCHEMA [clr]')
GO

-- Add a database user in the SQLCLR_Net Database for the Login
CREATE USER [BaselCLRLogin] FOR LOGIN [BaselCLRLogin]
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY BaselCLR
FROM 'D:\BASEL\BS_Assemblies\BaselCLR.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE clr.CheckFileFormat(
    @fileName nvarchar(255)
    , @seperator nvarchar(1)
    , @lineTerminator tinyint
    , @encoding tinyint
    , @headerFieldCount int
    , @bodyFieldCount int
    , @footerFieldCount int
    , @reason nvarchar(max) out)
AS
EXTERNAL NAME BaselCLR.StoredProcedures.CheckFileFormat
GO
```

If there's anything else I've done that are no, no's let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the following line...

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'BaselCLRLogin')
```

You're looking for the login name in the wrong system table!

Select from `sys.syslogins` instead.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.syslogins WHERE [sid] = SUSER_SID('BaselCLRLogin'))
    DROP LOGIN [BaselCLRLogin]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You must sign each assembly with a different key.

Comment: From the script aren't I creating the key from the dll file? i.e. I would have two separate and different keys.  I have two logins, the assemblies share schema though.  I've only shown the script for one dll btw.